# How can we prevent the Media Bias?

Tags: worldbuilding-process

How can we prevent the Media Bias? I think it's a signifcant issue our world is facing today

Comment: I want to preempt people who might vote to close this question. It is a broad question, yes, so I thought about voting to close. But I think it is also a good world-building question with relevance to near-term sci-fi. I think it should stay open.

Comment: It was difficult for me to choose just one reason to close this. Too Broad, Opinion-Based, and Off-Topic.

Comment: Opinion based? No. He asked for a procedural mechanism for preventing bias. Off topic? I cited David Brin in my answer, but there are other whole sci-fi and fantasy novels these days oriented around media interactions and hypothetical media constructs. It is very critical part of world building for any post-Singularity story.

Comment: Hi, jdmtj, welcome to Worldbuilding Stack Exchange. Can you explain how your question is about worldbuilding, as opposed to the real world?

Comment: @ErinThursby I'm going with off-topic.

Comment: Also, could you provide any credible source of information to back your claim?

Comment: It might help if you clarified what you mean by bias. Accuracy? Agenda? Favoring the other guy?

Comment: @SRM Opinion-based, sure, there are lots of different opinions one could have as far as bias prevention. There was nothing procedural in the question at all--no research behind it, nothing. Off-topic: it's framed with "it's a significant issue our world is facing today" rather than specific to a built world. If he'd said "in a world where are media is filtered through the human brain" or something, I would deem it world building.

Comment: @SRM Also, not a single word was said regarding sci-fi from the poster. For all we know they are setting their world in the 1920s. And there are not steam-punk rockets. I could go on and on about the advent of so-called "yellow journalism" and the way the industry self-policed (and didn't). How this is handled very much depends on the world, the tech level and cultural factors. Without those, it's a shot in the dark. He said "facing today" so I would have to assume it's not sci-fi or any other era, but modern day, and in our world. The poster DID say "our world."

Comment: It's also opinion-based because defining bias is opinion-based.

Comment: Alright. I'll accept the critique of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A StackExchange style reputation system for news reports. The system of managing privileges based on points has worked very well. I've been looking at what it would take to make a news site out of the SE platform. It doesn't work cleanly as it stands, but i think something like it (with some Slashdot.org metamoderation) is the future.

For relevant example in science fiction, read David Brin's "Existence" novel.

Note that Reddit is a good start on this but personally I don't think it has the right community self-management setup.

Comment: Note: many systems work when everyone is volunteering their time but fail when paychecks are on the line.

Comment: True.  That's one of the aspects I've been thinking about.

Comment: you also have a problem that lots of followings could swamp upvote an inaccurate but politically favorable statement. Stack Exchange is partially shielded by just not being interesting to such people. I mean modern media is often social media these days which is already based on popularity.

Answer (score 3):

Can we define Media Bias in a way which, itself, is not biased?  It's a surprisingly tricky concept.  If I am reading a scientific journal, I expect it to be peer reviewed to bias the articles towards those which are worth reading.

Bias, of course, implies that there is a correct version of reporting.  We measure media bias by comparing against this correct version, but what is correct?  One of the phrases most quoted is "just report the news," which sounds brilliant, until you realize just how much news there is.  If we reported "all the news," each newspaper would be a billion pages thick.  And that's not even counting the Sunday edition.  We *expect* a filter to be applied to the news.  That's one of the things we pay the media for.  We want them to help us identify what is important, so that we don't have to.

So, from a world building perspective (which is the valid perspective on this question for this site), if one is building a story about media bias, its worth noting that the bias is actually *desired*.  A story which seeks to erase media bias will have to deal with this paradoxical problem.

And remember, history goes to the victor.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of seeming mathematically pedantic, I think that the *variance* in the media is a bigger problem -- the large (and IMHO widening) spreading out of what's trustable vs. what is not.  Yes, there's more and more data, but much of it more noise than signal.  I think Neil Stephenson termed it "the Bullshyte problem" in his novel Anathem.  Mis/Dis-information isn't new, but the internet and social media give "Bullshyters" great leverage.

Comment: worse popularity algorithms can actually favor disinformation, people tend to like things that support their world view not challenge it.